# Possible effects of mixing dependencies versions

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Recently I wanted to update my app's dependencies, as I saw new version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 library came up (27.0.0). After incrementing this lib version, Android Studio underlines this library and shows a popup with error message:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.0.0, 25.2.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-v13:25.2.0

I've run gradlew app:dependencies command and saw other dependency which uses android support lib but it's older version - 25.2.0. My question is: what should I do? I assume I have to downgrade android support lib version as otherwise I may see No Method Found or No Class Found errors, am I right? Is it possible to include both of these versions somehow, that the library causing conflicts will be still able to use older version?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You could exclude the old version from that library

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote already, one way is to downgrade to the lowest version. But I think that as long as you are not using that specific methods that the library with older dependency is using, you should be fine. But for the sake of safety, you should have all the dependecies of the same version